# If "pending" is a preposition, why not "awaiting" and "remaining"

Tags: differences, prepositions

I have found these three examples of *pending*, *awaiting*, and *remaining* from Your Dictionary, all of which show that they are prepositions:

> 1. Philip, who had been left in charge of Palestine **pending** the decision and had won the respect of Varus, became tetrarch of Batanaea, Trachonitis and Auranitis, with ioo talents.
> 2. Katie held her breath, **awaiting** the awful news.
> 3. We stole one weekend together, **remaining** in New York, before answering a summons to join the others in Massachusetts.

According to the officially compiled dictionaries:

- *Pending* is an adjective as well as preposition.
- *Remaining* and *awaiting* are both adjectives.

**Why are *remaining* and *awaiting* not prepositions?**

Comment: "Pending" is a prep because it has no understood subject. The others do.

Comment: Also, where "pending" takes an obligatory NP complement, it's a prep. Elsewhere, it's an adjective. [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pending)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sentences 2) and 3), it seems to me that the words *awaiting* and *remaining* can easily be analyzed as participles (verb forms) because they seem to have logical subjects (Katie is awaiting the awful news, and "we" are remaining in New York).

The word *pending* in sentence 1) can't be analyzed the same way, which I guess is why it is classified as a preposition.

---

A side note: despite what the dictionaries you looked at say, I'm having trouble coming up with a context where *awaiting* and *remaining* are unambiguously adjectives rather than participles. Some people apparently believe that participles usually do not occur attributively, in contexts like "the remaining minutes" or "the awaiting crowd", but I've never understood how this position is justified—to me, it seems possible that *remaining* and *awaiting* are participles rather than adjectives even in this context.

The "very" test for proving that a word is an adjective doesn't seem to work for either word.

The *un-* negation test (negative *un-* doesn't attach to verbs, but does attach to adjectives) fails, as far as I can tell, for *awaiting* (**unawaiting* seems to hardly exist). *Unremaining* seems to be better established (although still rare): I supppose that implies that *remaining* does in fact have an adjectival as well as a verbal use.

Comment: Great answer with perfect analysis.